# How to add new controllers to devise controllers structure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

i have a functional application that have a devise merchant model and i've overwritted the registration controller, so i have a folders structure like

```
app/controllers/merchants/registrations_controller.rb
```

now i'm trying to add a new controller called products in order to have something like

```
app/controllers/merchants/registrations_controller.rb
app/controllers/merchants/products_controller.rb
```

When i perform

```
rails g controller
```

i get all the files required, but for some reason next to it i can't perform rake's or generators 'cause of this error

```
undefined method `devise' for #<Class:0x007f929f5b5408>
```

this ever happen when i add a new controller to a devise folder, in this case the merchants folder... is there a reason why i can not or i should not do this?

how can i accomplish this?
maybe there is a better approach to do this... if is that the case, could be great know it ;)

update: the goal is group all the controllers related to the merchants under merchants folder, also i figured out that the issue is generated by a helper file generated in app/helpers/merchants/products_helper.rb so deleting this file the exception dissapears... but why?

Comment: Don't really know why this error happens but it seems to me you are in the wrong direction here: source folders hierarchies are not meant to represent entities relationships in RoR (like the products / merchants one). Usually what you do is you have a flat hierarchy of controllers with constraints in them (ex: check that a merchant is authenticated on the 'edit' actions of the products_controller) and handle hierarchy through nested resources (http://bit.ly/aFFgpE). If you create 'admins' tomorrow, you won't want to recreate fully new products controllers / views / ... for them

Comment: I know folders hierachy does not mean anything, the reason to do it is to organize controllers related to merchant in the same folder due to for an admin it have a different functionallity

Answer (score 0):

Why did you add the products_controller to your devise merchants folder? If the goal is to authenticate merchants for the products controller, here is the way to do it:

Put your product_controller.rb in app/controller/ as usual and had this filter in it:

```
before_filter authenticate_merchant!
```

Check that you have this in your route.rb (for the custom registrations controller):

```
devise_for :merchants, :controllers => {:registrations => "merchants/registrations"}
```

Comment: because i'll have another products controller for a general use, also i'll have a products controller for the customers (Users)